# Azure Logic Apps - Twitter Connector Fails

Tags: azure, twitter, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App with Twitter connector that searches for tweets with a keyword. It has been working fine but now it suddenly started failing.

When I look at the output of the Twitter connector, below is the body it returns.

```
"body": {
        "status": 500,
        "source": "https://twitterconnectorce8207a3c04d4ebdbf35f4e3fdcee1a4.azurewebsites.net/search/tweets?Query=AisChinaSupport&MaxResults=20",
        "message": "An error has occurred."
    }
```

Comment: Can you go to the API App, then Gateway and restart the Gateway?

Comment: I did go the TwitterConnector API app and restarted the Gateway but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I would just delete it and create a new one. It might be the token, it might be the GW went busted, there are a bunch of things that can cause that and they are not easy to debug like that. Sorry you had to hit this. If it happens again, please reach out to me pakefali[at]microsoft and we'll go on from there.

Comment: Tried that but encountered same issue.

Comment: I was on a hackathon last week and I think they said there was a known issue with the twitter connector at the moment.